# Como filtrar por el mes en una columna de un dataframe

Tags: python

Necesito filtrar por el mes de enero en el siguiente `dataframe`:

| row | Time | Arctic | Antarctica |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1990-01-01 | 12.72 | 3.27 |
| 1 | 1990-02-01 | 13.33 | 2.15 |
| 2 | 1990-03-01 | 13.44 | 2.71 |
| 3 | 1990-04-01 | 12.16 | 5.10 |
| 4 | 1990-05-01 | 10.84 | 7.37 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 250 | 2010-11-01 | 8.06 | 11.75 |
| 251 | 2010-12-01 | 10.02 | 6.67 |
| 252 | 2011-01-01 | 11.38 | 2.87 |
| 253 | 2011-02-01 | 12.32 | 1.80 |
| 254 | 2011-03-01 | 12.40 | 2.18 |

255 rows × 3 columns

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? ¿Qué código necesito?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento? Lee [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es usar de la librería de `pandas` el `DatetimeIndex` el cual te devolverá el índice de esa columna fecha que tienes, solo le tienes que especificar si lo que quieres que te regrese es el día, el mes o el año. La sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Time']).month
```

Aquí encontraras como se vería la salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sea de utilidad

¡Saludos!